# How to process when all the files completes and place done in camel

Tags: cron, apache-camel

I am newbie to camel. Let me explain my business requirement, i have some 10 files in **Folder A**. In particular time all these 10 files will be processed and do the business logic and move the files to **Folder B**. Each file place one done file respectively. I need to process files from **Folder B** for next business operation. But i need to start this process only when all the 10 done files are placed. until complete all the 10 files in my previous process, i should not start this process. How to do this in camel.

Note:
i dont want to use any cron for my second route.
10 file is assumption. it may be dynamic

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can an [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) to aggregate the processed files before continuing the second part of processing.

You will have something similar to the following:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file://<Folder A>" />

  <!-- your business logic -->

  <aggregate strategyRef="aggregatorStrategy" ...>
    ...
  </aggregate>

  <!-- here goes the business logic used to poll files from Folder B -->

</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a "alldone" file:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file://<Folder A>?scheduler=<particular time>" />
  <!-- your business logic part 1-->
  <to uri="file://<Folder B>" />
  <choice>
    <when>
      <simple>${exchangeProperty.CamelBatchComplete}</simple>
      <setBody><constant>null</constant></setBody>
      <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <simple>alldone</simple>
      </setHeader>
      <to uri="file://<Folder B>" />
    </when>
  <choice>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="file://<Folder B>?doneFileName=alldone" />
  <!-- your business logic part 2-->
</route>
```